# Android can not run google map and return network error

Tags: java, android

i have write an android program to show google map and show the current location.

Here is a part of the code , please see:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,LocationListener {
public static GoogleMap googleMap;

private Geocoder geoCoder;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private List<Address> addressSearchList;
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION = 11;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_map);
    Log.d("Test","success0");
    geoCoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
    textView.setText(getString(R.string.TITLE_REPORT));
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            String addressName = adapter.getItem(position);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if ((addressSearchList == null) || (position >= addressSearchList.size()))
                return;
            Address address = addressSearchList.get(position);
            googleMap.clear();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(addressName)
                    .snippet(getString(R.string.CONFIRM))
            );
            marker.showInfoWindow();
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }

    });

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCancelSearch);
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            editText.setText("");
            editText.clearFocus();
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            list.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            try {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) && (v.getText().length() > 0)) {
                //Log.d("TEST", "onEditorAction");
                try {
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                String locationName = v.getText().toString();
                new SearchAddressTask(locationName).execute();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        //Log.d("TEST", "not success");
    } else {
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mapClinic");
        Log.d("Test","success1");
        fm.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
        Log.d("Test","success2");
    }
}



@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ///final GoogleMap googleMaps=googleMap;
    // Your code heregoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    //Log.d("TEST", clinic.getLongitude() + ":" + clinic.getLatitude());
    double latitude = 22.309994;
    double longitude = 114.226036;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));

    googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);


    final GoogleMap googleMapF= googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            googleMapF.clear();
            String address = "";
            //Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);
                if (addresses.size() <= 0)
                    return;
                //address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                StringBuilder longAddress = new StringBuilder();
                String temp;
                int j = 0;
                while ((temp = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(j++)) != null) {
                    longAddress.append(temp);
                }
                address = longAddress.toString();
                //EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textLocation);
                //editText.setText(addresses.get(0).getFeatureName());

                    /*addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName("�Ի��{", 10);
                    if (addresses.size() <= 0) {
                        Log.d("TEST", "can't find");
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("TEST", addresses.toString());
                        Log.d("TEST", "find it");
                    }*/
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Marker marker = googleMapF.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(point)
                    .title(address)
                    .snippet(getString(R.string.CONFIRM))
            );
            marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    });

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            LatLng point = marker.getPosition();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("LatLng", point);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });

    if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        Log.d("Test","success3...1");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );
    }

    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
    if (provider == null){
        Log.d("Test","success3");
        return;
    }
    Log.d("Test","success3.1");

    Location location = getLastKnownLocationS();
    //Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    Log.d("Test", "success4");
    if (location != null) {
        Log.d("Test", "success5");
        LatLng point = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        Log.d("Test", "success6");
        googleMap.clear();
        String address = "";
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        Log.d("Test", "success7");
        try {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() <= 0)
                return;
            //address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            StringBuilder longAddress = new StringBuilder();
            String temp;
            int j = 0;
            Log.d("Test", "success8");
            while ((temp = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(j++)) != null) {
                longAddress.append(temp);
            }
            address = longAddress.toString();
            Log.d("Test", "success9");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("Test", "success10");
        Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(point)
                .title(address)
                .snippet(getString(R.string.CONFIRM))
        );
        Log.d("Test", "success11");
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        Log.d("Test", "success12.1");
        onLocationChanged(location);
        Log.d("Test", "success12.2");
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 10000, 0, this);
    Log.d("Test", "success13");
}

private Location getLastKnownLocationS() {
    LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    if( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
        Log.d("Test","success3...2");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[] {  android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION  },
                MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION );
    }
    for (String provider : providers) {



        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            // Found best last known location: %s", l);
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    Log.d("Test","success_async");
    return bestLocation;
}
```

Updated the error parts,please help ,thanks for reminds the error occur in onLocationChanged method, Thanks.

Updated the error parts,please help ,thanks for reminds the error occur in onLocationChanged method, Thanks

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        Log.d("Test","onLocationChange");
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
    }
```

And debugger have below error:

```
10-26 08:47:12.493 26361-26361/com.afcd.redtidesystem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.afcd.redtidesystem, PID: 26361
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.moveCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)' on a null object reference
                                                                            at com.afcd.redtidesystem.MapActivity.onLocationChanged(MapActivity.java:379)
                                                                            at com.afcd.redtidesystem.MapActivity.onMapReady(MapActivity.java:329)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzaj.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
                                                                            at gl.b(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518470:20)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518470:5)
                                                                            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB@11518470:5)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Comment: You didn't include the relevant part of the code. The NPE happens inside the ``onLocationChanged`` method.

Comment: in onMapReady try first line as googleMap  = googleMap; (global variable googleMap  = on map ready parameter )

Comment: Hi f1sh, have updated the code , please help ,Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1-Add these line to your onCreate() method if you are getting your map from map fragment

SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

2- Uncomment your first line in onMapReady() method

Comment: Hi Ikram Hussain , Have tried return same error, thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

i have changed your code ,try this one , if error comes in onLocationChangd()

@Override public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
 {

if(Location!=null)
{

// You code here

}
}

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 CameraUpdate center=
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng( 73.35687586412547,
                                                 -45.77172998180484));
    CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10);

    map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom);
```

let me know if any query